# Convert API URL to “data:image/png;base64" by PHP

Tags: php, base64

The following API URL has an output in PNG image:

http://qrfree.kaywa.com/?l=1&s=8&d=google.com

I want convert the API URL to “data:image/png;base64” (DATA URL / DATA URI) with the similar to the PHP code example below:

```
$image = ("<img src = http://qrfree.kaywa.com/?l=1&s=8&d=google.com"); // False! (only example!)
//or
$image = 'real-picture.png'; // True!

$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
$src = 'data:image/png;base64,'.$imageData;
echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
```

However, the above code works with a real picture which has specified format and if replaced with the API URL, cannot read image path.
How the code should be corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a web request to `http://qrfree.kaywa.com/?l=1&s=8&d=google.com` returns an image of type image/png, you can do ...

```
$image = "http://qrfree.kaywa.com/?l=1&s=8&d=google.com";
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,', 
    base64_encode(file_get_contents($image)),
    '">';
```

`file_get_contents()` expects either a valid file name or a valid http(s) request.  Your code was passing in something starting with some HTML `<img ...`